# Magento 2: Getting Error on running setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, extensions, upgrade, url-rewrite, setup-upgrade

I updated a few modules after upgrading the Magento version to 2.4.3 from 2.3.0 and I am getting this error on running setup:upgrade command: "URL key for specified store already exists"

Please help.

Comment: There's duplicate url keys inside of url_rewrite table probably, try check inside the table for duplicates

Comment: Tried that but it didnt work. It was showing due to an extension, I have disabled it for now.

Answer (score 0):

check out this link related to the above issue solution
https://www.human-element.com/url-key-specified-store-already-exists-magento-2

Thank You